# How to deploy Node JS based API in Ubuntu server for production

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, web-deployment

I never worked on `Linux`. So if it is very basic question, sorry for that.

I have a `node.js` based REST API. This API is using

- Node.js
- Express
- CORS

I need to deploy this API for production on an Ubuntu 16.04 server. I have done faq research and able to work with a simple hello.js app which returns a simple string. However, whenever I try deploying real app, I get error like

```
./server.js: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

If you point me to any step by step guide, it would be a great help.

Comment: install nodejs and npm, and install the libs with npm, then run the init script

Comment: I have done those steps. Following this one : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: publish the code here to check it

Comment: I think, you are using ecma6 feature without 'use strict'

Comment: It looks like the problem in the server.js script, not with the deployment. You need to at least post the server.js here.

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file add the following in the scripts section.

```
scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
```

so you can start your server via command line

```
node server
```

or

```
npm start
```

The problem is when you run `./server.js` , it actually thinks it's a Bash script. Bash scripts are executed in that way.